# Poco libraries - include share library in Android via CMakeList.txt

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, poco-libraries

I'm using cmakelist in my source code android to include Poco library with function:

```
add_subdirectory(src/main/cpp/libs/Poco)
```

But it cannot find OpenSSL and compile Crypto in Poco. Please help.